# getaddrinfo isn't resolving hostnames

Tags: linux, networking, dns, getaddrinfo

```
nc -zv cms-01 5061
```

Fails with:
    nc: getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname

But ping/dig work just fine. You can see the different most with getent:

```
# getent hosts cms-01
172.17.2.108    cms-01.docker
```

But with "ahosts" instead of "hosts", it returns nothing.

```
# getent ahosts cms-01
```

"ahosts" uses `getaddrinfo` just like `nc`, so why is it failing to resolve the hostname even though it exists in dns? BTW, it doesn't change if I use the full hostname ("cms-01.docker" vs "cms-01").

Answer (score 0):

Domain names will cause this, especially if your domain name search doesn't include docker.

Add this to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.1 terse.domain.com
```

Now try to look this up:

```
% getaddrinfo terse
getaddrinfo: Name does not resolve
% getaddrinfo terse.domain.com
dgram inet udp 192.168.1.1 0
stream inet tcp 192.168.1.1 0
seqpacket inet sctp 192.168.1.1 0
```

Update the /etc/hosts to:

```
192.168.1.1 terse.domain.com terse
```

It now works:

```
% getaddrinfo terse
dgram inet udp 192.168.1.1 0
stream inet tcp 192.168.1.1 0
seqpacket inet sctp 192.168.1.1 0
```

If using resolv.conf, you may add a search line:

```
search domain.com docker
```